# How to merge different Powershell macros into one?

Tags: powershell

Since .NET Core is out I've been using more and more the command line as way of working and in general I'm using a lot PowerShell.

Whilst Visual Studio Code is very command line friendly, it can't be said the same for its big brother.

To improve the situation I have added the following to my $PROFILE file.

```
function Execute-VisualStudioAsAdmin
{
    if ($args.Count -gt 0)
    {
        Start-Process "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" $args -Verb RunAs
    }
    else
    {
        Start-Process "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" -Verb RunAs
    }
}

Set-Alias vsa Execute-VisualStudioAsAdmin -Option ReadOnly

Set-Alias vs "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" -Option ReadOnly
```

Now I can do

```
PS> vs

PS> vsa

PS> vs .\Solution.sln

PS> vsa .\Solution.sln
```

Everything works as expected but it's not as good as I would like. Maybe I'm overthinking it, but I wonder if there is a way to create a better function and have both aliases using it by passing different parameters.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
function Start-VisualStudio {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [Alias("vs")]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$AsAdmin,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $false,
            ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true
        )]
        [string[]]$ArgumentList
    )
    process {
        $parameters = @{
            FilePath = "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
        } 
        if ($AsAdmin.ToBool()) {
            $parameters["Verb"] = "RunAs"
        }
        # Allow no null or empty arrays or values
        $ArgumentList  = @($ArgumentList | where {"$_" -ne ""})
        if ($ArgumentList.Count -gt 0) {
            $parameters["ArgumentList"] = $ArgumentList 
        }
        Start-Process @parameters
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

```
vs
vs .\Solution.sln
vs .\Solution.sln -AsAdmin
```

**Explanations:**

`[CmdletBinding()]` makes a function work like a compiled cmdlet. [=> MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-6)

`[Alias()]` allows you to define the alias inside the function. [=> MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/alias-attribute-declaration)

`ValueFromRemainingArguments` makes an array from all arguments that are not `-AsAdmin`. [=> MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#valuefromremainingarguments-argument)

`@parameters` is called "splatting". [=> MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6)

Comment: @Kralizek You're welcome. I've added some more doc links and also made some improvements to the code.